# Difference between function call

Tags: javascript, function

while calling a function in javascript , we generally call it by myFunction() ,(myFunction is a random function) but in the code given below btn.onclick=bgChange is given without () , how is that possible ? Should'nt it return function description instead?

```
  var btn = document.querySelector('button');
  function random(number) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*number);
  }
  function bgChange() {
    var rndCol = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;
  }
  btn.onclick = bgChange;
```

Comment: That is called a callback function, it is actually invoked when the onclick function is triggered.  It says let btn.onclick point to that function and execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`btn.onclick = bgChange;` doesn't call function, it adds click handler (callback). When user clicks on button, it will invoked: `btn.onclick();` - your handler stored in `btn.onclick` property will be called. In your case it will be the same as call `bgChange();`

Comment: but how it is the same , I read the tagged question too but if I define a function like  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>  we use () at the end , here we aren't

Comment: in `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>` value of `onclick` attribute isn't handler, it's JS script called after click. `btn.onclick = bgChange;` === `onclick="bgChange();">Click me</button>`

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp for more info

Comment: see this   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my text color.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
here it is called by myFunction()

Comment: here it isn't <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example demonstrates how to assign an "onclick" event to the window object.</p>

<p>Click anywhere in this window to change the background color of body.</p>

<script>
window.onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: As I said before - in JS you set handler, in HTML you set js script which will be called after click. This script can be random, not just function call, e g `onclick="myFunction(); myFunction();"` will be valid

Comment: could you please please elaborate I'm kinda stuck on it since 2 days

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181567/discussion-between-ingvar-and-himanshu-jotwani).